# Dynamic ng-Grid with JSON data in angularJS?

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-grid

I want to make a dynamic ng-grid , which adjusts its columns according to the key values in my JSON object. JSON object is fetched from an api. the problem I am facing is defining columns at runtime i.e The columns are not available at design time but will only be available only at runtime. I want to have something like :

http://plnkr.co/edit/q1Ye10OsIn9NOJmrICyD?p=preview

So that, I have as many columns as keys in my Json object. API's can vary so I need to make a grid which adjusts its columns.

My plunker is not working, but I hope it gives you idea, what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want, you don't need to mess with `columnDefines`.  Just having this:

```
faculty.controller('facultycontroller', function facultycontroller($scope, $http, $window){
    $scope.facdata = [];
    
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'facdata'
    };

    $http.get("http://mtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/institute").then(function (result) {
         $scope.facdata = result.data;
         console.log($scope.facdata[0]);
    });
});
```

will create the grid with a column for each key in your json.

### Update

If you want to filter out any columns that begin with '$', you can do something like this:

```
angular.forEach(result.data[0], function(value, key){
    if(key.indexOf('$') != 0)
        $scope.columnDefines.push({ field: key, displayName: key});
});
```

Actually, you were close with what you were trying to do.  You just need to put the columnDefines variable on $scope, and assign it to the gridOptions using a string, like this:

```
$scope.columnDefines = [];

$scope.gridOptions = {
  data: 'facdata',
  columnDefs: 'columnDefines'
};
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5VkBTGP2o3gGANe9wuNQ?p=preview)

Comment: I have tried this. This has a problem, it prints some additional columns, for example, $id, i dont want it to get printed but it will if i go by this method. Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching your columnDefines variable to the scope ($scope.columnDefines). Then in your options do this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = 
  {
    data: 'facdata',
    columnDefs: 'columnDefines' //Note the quotes            
  };
```

This will make ng-grid watch your columnDefs for changes

Comment: columndefines is correctly defined, as grid is showing that column(student) I have defined inside it.